# PHP fuzzy search 2 columns and return best matches

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've got a search puzzle I need to solve, but my skillset is minimal, so apologies if I don't explain this well.  To try and demonstrate the problem, here is an example of the data in two database columns:

```
  | Start address        | End address          |
-----------------------------------------------
1 | Essex                | Moortown, Leeds      |
2 | Place A, London      | Place B, Manchester  |
3 | Townsville, Essex    | Leeds Town Hall      |
4 | Essex Trading Estate | Another Leeds Estate |
5 | Somewhere, Devon     | Yeoville             |
6 | ...                  | ...                  |
```

If, for example, a user submits "21 Some Street, Essex" and "Leeds some place" in the corresponding form fields, I need to search the MySQL database and pull back the top X number of best matches, which in this example would be rows 1, 3 and 4, as they all contain Essex in the first column and Leeds in the second.

I can see that PHP has two functions similar_text() and levenshtein(), which may help with this, but I'm not sure which is the more appropriate for this sort of part matching and how to get the most accurate search results.  I've not found anything similar within MySQL.

Is anybody with experience of this able to give me any pointers, please?

Cheers

Andy

Comment: You could try putting a `FULLTEXT` compound index across both fields and use MySQL's natural language search : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: You can look into using MySQL's [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple like function to get the required search output. To make overcome the case sensitive use lower or upper.

```
select start_address,end_address from table where lower(start_address) like '%urfirststring%'
and lower(end_address) like '%ursecondstring%'
```

Pass your search strings also in lower .

Comment: Thanks Rams.  However, the example I've used has common words in both the form entry fields and the database columns (e.g. towns or cities), but these are mixed in with less important words that are unique to every entry (such as road names or postcodes).  I want to match up form field 1 to column 1 and field 2 to column 2, with results in order of most relevant match.